# Dependency injection with service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented a service layer in my MVC application that handles all the CRUD business logic. My question is, does this way of injecting dependency of context and other instances into the service class is a good approach or there is an alternative way of doing it ?

```
public class Admin: Controller
{
  private readonly AdminServices _adminServices;
  
  public Admin(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    _adminServices = new AdminServices(context, userManager, roleManager);
  }
}

public class AdminServices{ 
  public AdminServices(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
  {
    // code
  }
}
```

PS: I don't use interfaces for the service layer due to the overhead it brings to maintain but also because I won't be using unit testing or do other fancy stuff with the application in the long term.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really dependency injection (DI), one of the main, I guess you could call it feature, of DI is decoupling different implementations from each other, but like this your `Admin` controller is still explicitly dependent on `AdminServices`

Comment: No, you are not injecting anything. The whole point of DI is *not* creating instances yourself (which you are doing in `Admin` class). If your DI Container is set up properly, `AdminServices` *should* be able to resolve `ApplicationDbContext`, `UserManager<IdentityUser>`, `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` on it's own.

Comment: I guess the only way for the AdminServices to resolve the classes on it's own is if I implement Service layer with interfaces so it can get injected at startup ?

Comment: Correct @Alex. Your code currently is not using dependency injection. Make sure to create an interface for your service and register it correctly within the startup.cs